# Xpath and arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath

I am scraping a webpage for text, using the code as follows

```
doc.xpath("//td[text()='Operating system']/following-sibling::td")
doc.xpath("//td[text()='Processors']/following-sibling::td")
```

I have about 30 of these so I thought I could maybe use an array but its not working, here is my code

```
clues = Array.new
clues << 'Operating system'
clues << 'Processors'
clues << 'Chipset'

clues.each do |clue_storeage|
doc.xpath("//td[text()=#{clues}]/following-sibling::td")
end
```

Is there a way I can feed the array into that loop and then output that to a CSV?

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but in your array version there are no quotations around the text. Try changing it to: `...text()='#{clues}']...`.

Comment: I m not clear on how you are populating your array, but one mistake I see is that your running your doc.xpath on the array instead of on an object in the array.  doc.xpath("//td[text()=#{clues}]/following-sibling::td") clues is the name of your array.  I think it should be doc.xpath("//td[text()=#{clue_storage}]/following-sibling::td") which is an object in your array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify mb2nd's comment, your each block is incorrectly referencing the array.  This should work:

```
clues.each do |clue|
  doc.xpath("//td[text()=#{clue}]/following-sibling::td")
end
```

To output the captured data to CSV you could run:

```
csv = ""
clues.each do |clue|
  csv << doc.xpath("//td[text()=#{clue}]/following-sibling::td")
  csv << ", " unless clues.last == clue
end
```

The doc.xpath("//td[text()=#{clue}]/following-sibling::td") call may need .value on the end?

On a side note; you may also populate your array like so:

```
clues = ['Operating system', 'Processors', 'Chipset']
```

---

EDIT (after last comment from @Ninja2K)

You need to save the result of each the xpath calls.  Here's some working code:

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'nokogiri' 
require 'open-uri' 

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ie/en/ho/WF06b/321957-321957-3329742-89318-89318-5186820-5231694.html?dnr=1%22"))

clues = ['Operating system', 'Processors', 'Chipset'] 

csv_text = ""
clues.each do |clue|
  csv_text << doc.at_xpath("//td[text()='#{clue}']/following-sibling::td").text
  csv_text << ", " unless clues.last == clue
end
puts csv_text
```

BTW. You may also find this article useful: http://hunterpowers.com/data-scraping-and-more-with-ruby-nokogiri-sinatra-and-heroku/

Comment: Ok I entered clues.each do |clue|
doc.xpath("//td...[text()='#{clues}']/following-sibling::td")
end  and it returns => ["Operating system", "Processors", "Chipset"] but I need the array values to enter that xpath piece

Comment: like so doc.xpath("//td<array_value>/following-sibling::td")

Comment: drop the s.   #{clue}  not #{clues}

Comment: or use another name:   clues.each do |sherlock| doc.xpath("//td...[text()='#{sherlock}']/following-sibling::td") end

Comment: Still the same ;( here is my full code require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'   
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ie/en/ho/WF06b/321957-321957-3329742-89318-89318-5186820-5231694.html?dnr=1")) clues = Array.new
clues << 'Operating system'
clues << 'Processors'
clues << 'Chipset'


clues.each do |sherlock|
doc.xpath("//td...[text()='#{sherlock}']/following-sibling::td")
end

Comment: including the full code allowed me to see the problem.  main answer now edited :)

Comment: Almost there Gef, it returns the correct information but the CSV is blank?  this piece [text()='#{sherlock} should be [text()='#{clue} right?

Comment: csv_text is not blank?  hard to understand without seeing all the code.  can you post your code in a gist? - https://gist.github.com/ or pastebin?

Comment: any luck finding the solution, I am still drawing a blank here literally :)

Comment: We're really deviating from the original query now, I think you need to close this & start up a new question.  Anyhow this outputs to a file - https://gist.github.com/211577f8cf2ea23f3775   (I've not bothered using the CSV gem, I think that's only really useful for reading CSV files, but as I said we're deviating from the original question... )